# How to handle next Next js Router Queries and Params

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

How can Next JS invalid query and params?
like: I want only to render `/page?id=*` but want to redirect page when it's not correct. Like `/page?p=*` or `/p?id=` or anything invalid I want to redirect.

Comment: Can't you just check for `id` and see if it's valid. If not just redirect?

Comment: We'll need more details, do you want to redirect on the client or on the server? What have you currently tried?

Answer (score 0):

use `getServerSideProps` and manage the query in that function, and using redirects or notFound

```js
const getServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
   if(query.id === "*") {
   //this will redirect to the 404 page
      return {
         notFound: true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `Error: Your `getServerSideProps` function did not return an object. Did you forget to add a `return`?`

Comment: In my example, the `getServerSideProps` only returns something when the id has a value of *, you may need to add a return outside the conditional